# Ho do you do the following file-related operations in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

How do you do the following operations in C++?

1. Opening Files
2. Closing Files
3. Reading Files
4. Writing Files

Answer (score 12):

### Reading

```
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream    inputFile("MyFileName")  // Opens a File.

    int  x;
    inputFile >> x; // Reads an integer from a file.

    std::string word;
    inputFile >> word; // Reads a space separated word from a file.

    double y;
    inputFile >> y; // Reads a floating point number from the file.

    // etc..
 } // File AutoMagically closed by going out of scope.
```

### Writing

```
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ofstream    inputFile("MyFileName")  // Opens a File.

    int  x = 5;
    inputFile << x << " "; // Writes an integer to a file then a space.
    inputFile << 5 << " "; // Same Again.

    std::string word("This is a line");
    inputFile << word << "\n"; // Writes a string to a file followed by a newline
                               // Notice the difference between reading and
                               // writing a string.
    inputFile << "Write a string constant to a file\n";

    double y = 15.4;
    inputFile << y << ":"; // Writes a floating point number 
                           // to the file followed by ":".

    // etc..
 } // File AutoMagically closed by going out of scope.
```

Comment: If you actually want to close a file early, you can do `file.close()`, but the scope-close is usually sufficient.  With outputting to a file, it is sometimes useful to weave in calls to `outputFile.flush()` to actually write the output at desired intervals.

Comment: @Tim:It is usually *not* desirable to close a file manually. There is the potential for an exception to be thrown. By letting the destructor close the file any exceptions are discarded. You should usually only use close() when you want to catch and compensate for such exceptions (eg logging).

Comment: @Tim: Yes you can use file.flush() or the std::endl or std::flush to flush the file. Usually this is not desirable as the buffer is designed to make the file as efficient as possible. Doing the flush manually will decrease performance. Though if you need the feedback to the user then it is acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

### All at once

```
{ 
    std::ifstream in("foo.txt"); /* opens for reading */
    std::ofstream out("bar.txt"); /* opens for writing */
    out << in.rdbuf(); /* streams in into out. writing and reading */
} /* closes automatically */
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files.html

I personally still use the C style fopen, fread, fwrite, etc, but that is more of preference than actually "correct".

Comment: I prefer the standard file functions to iostream as well :)

Comment: Absolutely. iostream makes it so difficult to do basic writing and custom formatting. I don't understand why it's considered an 'improvement'.

Answer (score 1):

With C++ you've got lots of choices for how to interact with files, especially if you are using one of the many frameworks around, like Qt, wxWidgets, or GLib. To summarize, the standard C++ library uses a streams based model of file access, via std::ifstream and std::ofstream. This is similar to what you see when using std::cout and is what @Martin's post exemplifies. You also have available the standard C library functions for reading and writing files, namely open(), close(), read() and write(). The f*() variants take a FILE pointer rather than a file descriptor. The C variants are more useful when you want to treat a file as a raw stream of bytes, which unfortunately happens more often than it should. While both of these are "portable", constructing paths and handling directories/special files usually isn't, which is why you get things like boost::filesystem.